# Wordpress multisite seo

Tags: wordpress

Hey there, I am thinking of using wordpress multisite for a network of 30 blogs.

The questions is: every blog has its own directory, files etc.

With multisite and domain mapping, everything will become virtul, is this good for seo?

Second question: which do u think ranks better, a simple html seo site or  blog?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have good content SEO doesn't matter. However, that's not to say it should be ignored. You can use WordPress MU with either subdomins like myblog.example.com or folders like example.com/myblog I prefer subdomains but both are fine for SEO. A third option (and sounds like what you would like to do) is map each blog to a domain such as myblog.com and myotherblog.com which is fine too. I think the main thing is if you use domain mapping each site is being seen as a different site instead of an extension of the original site (I could be wrong here)

For your second question, they both rate the same as long as the site is structured correctly. I will state again that people put to much effort into SEO and not into created good content that people want to read.

Answer (score 0):

Using WordPress Multisite makes managing websites so much easier, and there are hundreds of plugins to enhance the functionality.

In terms of SEO I would Suggest [Yoast SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) because it has built in multisite support and makes managing the SEO for every site a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a blog would inherit better SEO as it will be added to more frequently.  Regarding multisites I would say just be careful not to replicate content across the sites as identical or similar content on different URLs can affect one or both of their natural rankings.

If however the sites are all different and you are just putting all your different blogs in to a single install there should be no need to worry too much, on bit of advice I would say is to NOT network activate plugins unless that is the only way to activate them as it injects the master sites url to get the resources for that plugin but activating it on each site ensures the plugin knows the url for that site and will deliver the content from the site you are on.